# why javascript is running over my prior html

Tags: javascript, html

new in js and couldnt find an answer for that.
I think its pretty basic BUT

my js code in deleting any html I write before.
what i would like to be happen - when pressing "load" button the script will run and create buttons without deleting the "load" button itself and h1 tag.

appreciate your help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>



</head>
<body>




<h1>check</h1>

<button onclick="printbtns()">load</button> 

<script> 
 
 
 function printbtns()
 {
  gobtns('A',18);
  gobtns('B',19);
  gobtns('C',20);
  gobtns('D',21);
  gobtns('E',22);
  gobtns('G',9);
 }

 function gobtns(letter,numberofstorages)
 {
 //window.alert("sometext");
 document.write(letter); 
 document.write("<br>");
 var i;


 for (i=1; i<=numberofstorages; i++){ 
  var str1=letter.concat(i);
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode(str1);
  btn.setAttribute("style","color:red;font-size:23px");
  btn.appendChild(t);
  btn.setAttribute("id", str1);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
 }

 document.write("<br><br>");
 }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what document.write is supposed to do

Comment: Use appendChild with new br elements instead, exactly the way you do for the button element. appendChild will append the node to the existing document. document.write will overwrite the document

Comment: For the `letter`, you might want to make it the text content of a new span element and append that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` will *erase the current document* if the document is already loaded - better to use a more modern, less confusing method of inserting new content, such as creating elements with `createElement` / `appendChild` or using `.innerHTML`:

```
function insertBR() {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

and

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(letter));
insertBR();`document.write` will *erase the current document* if the document is already loaded - better to use a more modern, less confusing method of inserting new content, such as creating elements with `createElement` / `appendChild` or using `.innerHTML`:
```

```js
function printbtns() {
  gobtns('A', 18);
  gobtns('B', 19);
  gobtns('C', 20);
  gobtns('D', 21);
  gobtns('E', 22);
  gobtns('G', 9);
}

function insertBR() {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
function gobtns(letter, numberofstorages) {
  insertBR();
  //window.alert("sometext");
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(letter));
  insertBR();
  var i;


  for (i = 1; i <= numberofstorages; i++) {
    var str1 = letter.concat(i);
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode(str1);
    btn.setAttribute("style", "color:red;font-size:23px");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    btn.setAttribute("id", str1);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }

  insertBR();
  insertBR();
}
```

```html
<h1>check</h1>
<button onclick="printbtns()">load</button>
```